# How to find the position of a sample signal in the main signal?

Tags: c++, c, matlab, signals, signal-processing

I have a main signal of 14 secs(120000 samples) which contains a sample signal inside it and I have the sample signal separately with me of 2 secs(20000 samples)(which are basically wave files). I want to find the position of the sample signal(i.e 2 secs signal) in the main signal in matlab.

I have tried looping logic for the above but the time taken to produce the output is too long.

I don't want to use the inbuilt cross correlation function of matlab.

Please suggest some method to obtain the result in minimum time(less than a minute).

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the cross-correlation feature of matlab? It would seem to be exactly what you'd want to use this situation.

Comment: Is the smaller sample signal and its copy lying inside the main signal, equal within some small tolerance? Also, does it occur as a "continuous" set of 20000 samples in the main signal? What I mean is, are there any noisy samples in between?

Comment: @uesp I wanted to find a different approach to do that.

Comment: @parag It is continuous 20000 samples and these 20000 samples are lying in the main signal also, but I want to find out the location of the sample signal(in secs).

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is you can convert your `main signal` and `sample signal` into `string` and use `regexp` to find out signal start point. Here is an example:

```
a=randn(1,120000); % main signal
b=a(100:20100); % Sample signal
sig_str=num2str(a); % Convert main signal into string
sampl_str=num2str(b); % Convert sample signal into string
sig_split=regexp(sig_str,sampl_str,'split');
sampl_sig_start_point=length(num2str(sig_split{1}))+1;
sampl_sig_end_point=sampl_sig_start_point+length(b)-1;
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I  dnt think you can escape from looping through all your 120,000.But to increase the spped of doing a correlation you can  try correlating first 5000 samples of 20,000 samples against the main 120,000 samples..If u get a good correlation at some point in main 120,000 samples then try correlating entire 20,000 samples against 120,000 samples at that point .  Basically you have to check for first part of ur signal in main signal and if u find ur first part at  some point u check for full part at that point ..